# TypeScript error with React & Slate: Property 'renderElement' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, slate.js

I am trying to learn how to use Slate vis-a-vis the following tutorial:  [Defining Custom Elements](https://docs.slatejs.org/walkthroughs/03-defining-custom-elements).

I have (following the tutorial with slight stylistic changes) added the following code:

```
export default function App() {
  const renderElement = useCallback((props) => {
    switch (props.element.type) {
      case "code":
        return <Code {...props} />
      default:
        return <Default {...props} />
    }
  }, [])

  return <Editor renderElement={renderElement} />
}
```

The problem is that I get the following TypeScript error:

```
Type '{ renderElement: (props: any) => Element; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
  Property 'renderElement' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'. ts(2322)
```

Any idea why I am getting this error and how to fix it?

Comment: Hi! Please post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the library in question, but from the documentation you linked it looks like the `renderElement` prop is on the `<Editable />` component rather than `<Editor />`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Yes, I forgot that I had made a base component for slate and I was not passing `renderElement` to the `<Editable />` component.